# Regex to match string in a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a strictly declared string in a sentence, the thread says:

> Find the position of the string "ten" within a sentence, without using the exact string directly (this can be avoided in many ways using just a bit of RegEx). Print as many spaces as there were characters in the original sentence before the aforementioned string appeared, and then the string itself in lowercase.

I've gotten this far:

```
let words = 'A ton of tunas weighs more than ten kilograms.'

function findTheNumber(){

         let regex=/t[a-z]*en/gi;
         let output = words.match(regex)
         console.log(words)
         console.log(output) 
}

console.log(findTheNumber())
```

The result should be:

```
input  = A ton of tunas weighs more than ten kilograms.
output =                                 ten(ENTER)
```

Comment: The `output` doesn't seem to match the requirements. Why are there spaces after 'ten'?

Comment: @MikeM It is the thread requirement, only keep the string "ten" and print "space" to replace other strings

Comment: "Print as many spaces as there were characters in the original sentence *before the aforementioned string appeared*, and then the string itself in lowercase."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
let text = 'A ton of tunas weighs more than ten kilograms.'

function findTheNumber(words){
    console.log( words.replace(/\b(t[e]n)\b|[^.]/g, (x,y) => y ?? " ") )
}
findTheNumber(text)
```

The `\b(t[e]n)\b` is basically `ten` whole word searching pattern.

The `\b(t[e]n)\b|[^.]` regex will match and capture `ten` into Group 1 and will match any char but `.` (as you need to keep it at the end). If Group 1 matches,  it is kept (`ten` remains in the output), else the char matched is replaced with a space.

Depending on what chars you want to keep, you may adjust the `[^.]` pattern. For example, if you want to keep all non-word chars, you may use `\w`.

Comment: `without using the exact string directly ` ... `t[e]n` nice XD

Comment: @GrafiCode This is a common trick in Linux to avoid outputting the current `grep` search command in `ps -ef` (list current processes) output, e.g. `ps -ef | grep [b]ash` will not output `grep --color=auto bash`

Comment: Ah, that exact recursion problem with ps | grep happened to me like a gazillion times... thanks for sharing!

Comment: Other ways to match `ten` with camouflaged regexps: [`\b(?=t)[a-z](?=e)[a-z](?=n)[a-z]\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ekt1jp/1), [`\b[a-z](?<=t)[a-z](?<=e)[a-z](?<=t)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ekt1jp/2), [`\b(?![a-su-z])[a-z](?![a-df-z])[a-z](?![a-mo-z])[a-z]\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ekt1jp/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you explain what this  (x,y) => y ?? " "  does?

Comment: @nsuspect *If Group 1 matches, it is kept (ten remains in the output), else the char matched is replaced with a space.* `y` is Group 1. `x` is the whole match value. If `y` is not `undefined`, or empty, if it participated in the match, the replacement is `y` (this way, `ten` that was captured into Group 1 is kept).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It looks very neat, I don't know if it is too much to ask, but can you show me another way of this (x,y) => y ?? " "  a little bit easier to understand. Because I just started learning Javascript recently, I'm still kind of a noob :))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I mean I am not quite getting used to writing in such a shortcode like this.

Comment: @nsuspect Please check the [*Conditional (ternary) operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) page.

Comment: @nsuspect Just occurred to me that I made a mistake in my previous comment that I deleted now. Actually, if Group 1 does not match, the replacement is a space, not `x`. Since we do not use `x` (the whole match) anywhere in replacement, we can reduce the `replace` to `.replace(/\b(t[e]n)\b|[^.]/g, (_,x) => x ?? " ")`. An unused variable is usually named as `_`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I also made a mistake, the result of the assignment requires me not to have the "." at the end of the sentence. I made some changes to the question, please take a look.

Comment: @nsuspect Then all you need to change is replace `[^.]` with `.` or `[\w\W]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I have that same idea, but I don't quite understand how to get the newline at the end of word "ten". Can you take a look again at my question, I just made some changes so you can easily imagine.

Comment: @nsuspect Just add `\n` to the `output`. `console.log(output + "\n")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah no no, I mean like this https://ibb.co/stFyFr9

Comment: @nsuspect The arrow is a newline, `\n`. The error on the screenshot says you have a trailing space. To remove trailing spaces, use `.trim()` on your output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, I use `.trimEnd()` it works great. But when I try to use other input like **" There are less than 10 words in this sentence. "**, the output didn't print out the **ten** string in the words **sentence**, I have no idea.

Comment: @nsuspect `\b` is a word boundary. Remove all `\b` if you are not interested in matching `ten` as a whole word.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see, thanks, I learned a lot from you. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I've seen it, very detail tutorial, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a regex replacement approach, with the help of a callback function:

```js
var input = "A ton of tunas weighs more than ten kilograms.";
var output = input.replace(/\w+/g, function(match, contents, offset, input_string)
{
    if (!match.match(/^[t][e][n]$/)) {
        return match.replace(/\w/g, " ");
    }
    else {
        return match;
    }
});
console.log(input);
console.log(output);
```

The above logic matches every word in the input sentence, and then selectively replaces every word which is *not* `ten` with an equal number of spaces.

Comment: Doesn't this use the "exact string directly"? Whatever that means exactly.

Comment: @MikeM It means that you cannot use the "ten" like Tim Biegeleisen did. The moment you use the words "ten" in IF...ELSE condition or something that is used for matching the words "ten" in the given input. The output will instantly throw out error " Prohibited word 'ten' found in the source code"

Comment: @nsuspect I don't see a way to do this without the string literal `"ten"` appearing _somewhere_.  You may abstract my approach above by putting the code into a function where `"ten"` gets passed as a parameter.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Trust me, I tried every possible ways to get over this trick thread, but whenever I use the whole word "ten" it doesn't matter where you put it, IF....ELSE or WHILE....LOOP, you will get that error. Which is why it gives us a hint to use Regex to bypass that

Comment: Check the edit, which contains a trivial change to use `match()` along with `[t][e][n]` to search for `ten`.

Comment: at this point, this would count as correct too: `String.fromCharCode(116) + String.fromCharCode(101) + String.fromCharCode(110)`